# Websocket - Connecting to a stream in Visual Basic

Tags: java, websocket, bitcoin, mtgox

I'm working on a project that will need real-time data from a website called MtGox.com. It is a market place for bitcoins. It has two options for obtaining current markets data, including buy/sell orders active for the virtual currency (Bitcoins - BTC). The first options, which I have had success implementing to my Visual Basic project is their API. The API can only be called once every 10 seconds, over that results in a 24 hour ban for your IP to protect against DoS attacks and such. The other option is using their public stream. I need to incorporate this into a VB project but am having problems finding examples or anybody with knowledge on the subject. [Here is a link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming) with a JavaScript example I believe, does anybody know how to make something similar for VB. They have a few different codes to choose from depending on the data stream you would like to subscribe to. I would like to subscribe to the "Depth" feed, which has a channel ID of "24e67e0d-1cad-4cc0-9e7a-f8523ef460fe". If I can get a working example of how to catch this feed in VB I will gladly donate some BTC to the person with the answer as soon as I can get the program working. Thanks and hope to hear from ya's.

Comment: I have actually been researching this for an average of 2-3 hours per day for around a week and a half now. I will note that I am not the most experienced of programmers. I am fairly rusty as it's been about 5 or 6 years since I've put serious effort into a program. I am eager to learn, and currently taking a 2 year college course on computer programming. I lost my eye at work and was sent back to school by my insurance company. This is just a side project but I am trying my best to figure it out. Best way to learn I figured was to dive right in, any and all information is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you post some initial code that you've written, it will improve the chances of getting answers.